# Bash script syntax error multiplying a variable with -1

Tags: bash

Am trying to mulitply a variable with -1 in bash script

this is the code

```
u=1
u=$(($u * -1))
if [ $u -eq 1 ]
then
rcolor="white"
#-----30
else
rcolor="#E8EDFF"
fi
```

Output

```
script.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `u=$(($u * 1))'
script.sh: line 2: `u=$(($u * 1))'
```

Comment: What shell? That should work in any POSIX shell. Does the script have windows line endings?

Comment: Yeah, this works for me exactly as-is, in bash 3.2.51 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Works for me also under either bash or dash.  Note that the code quoted in the error message differs (by a minus sign) from the code in the body of the script..

Comment: When every you get strange-looking syntax errors, a good bet is that your script has DOS line endings that confuse the `bash` parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `bc` or other calculator programs.

```
# echo "10*-1" | bc
-10
```

Comment: This sidesteps the actual problem. Multiplication by -1 is a reasonable thing to expect from `bash` arithmetic expressions.

Comment: this is in fact more portable than `bash`. `bash` doesn't support float

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to:

```
u=1
((u *= -1)) # no $
if [ $u -eq 1 ]
then
    rcolor="white"
#-----30
else
    rcolor="#E8EDFF"
fi
```